# How can I find my Outlook account using phone number only

Tags: outlook.com, account-recovery, outlook-on-the-web

I have created my Outlook mail before 2.5 years. Now I have forgot the email and password. I have only mobile number with me what I used while created account.

I have tried this link:
https://account.live.com/username/recover

But they showing only first two characters of my email - `ab****@outlook.com` and not showing full email address.

How can I get my email address?